# How to create table of Java enum using Eclipselink?

Tags: java, jpa, enums, eclipselink

I want a Java enum class being defined by the values which can be found in a database table.

Is this possible?? How?

I tried to go the other way:
I am wondering if it possible to let Eclipselink create a database table for an enum used in Java?
Let's say, I have an enum named Status with the values: AVAILABLE and OUT_OF_ORDER. 
How can I let JPA create the related database table (which should be some kind of lookup table to ensure that there can only be values contained in this table can be used in columns of any other table)?

Another example would be a record library with a class (or table respectively) Record which has a property (column) 'recordType'.

```
public enum RecordType {
NONE,
LP,
SINGLE
}
```

How can I tell JPA/Eclipselink to create a table called recordType? 
Using JPA Tools -> Make persistent ends up in an error in persistence.xml: *Listed class RecordType must not be an enum*.

Comment: Why?  You cannot dynamically add values to an enum at runtime. What it seems you want is an entity, where other tables instead of containing the reference type, contain a reference to the RecordTyoe table.  The entity would contain a string for the value so that it can be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you do not create a table with the possible values of your enum (you already got them on client side!)

You will instead store the value of the enum in a column. JPA allows you to store either the enum value 0,1,2... (highly discouraged) or the string value (AVAILABLE, ... far better!)

```
@Table(name = "the_name_of_your_table")
public class YourClass {

  @column(name = "the_column_name")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // <-Tells JPA to store the enum as a String
  private Status status; 

}
```

Comment: This would mean that if a further enum value must be added I have to rebuild the Java code rather than simply add a value to an 'enum' table!?

Comment: @user233552 Yes. But you plan to add some specific code for each value of the enum, then you have no other choice.

Comment: Do I? Sometimes it should just be ensured that a value of the table (enum) must be used rather that typing it manually. (In many other cases you're right, I think.)

Comment: @user233552 I forgot a word. I wanted to write : "But if you plan to add ..."

Comment: ;-) 
Eclipselink does create a column of type VARCHAR in MySql. Can I tell Eclipselink to create a column of type enum()? ...or isn't this possible because the enum type of a column is vendor (MySql) specific?